# Moving config files to a separate folder in React (Vite) project

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have an idea to put the configuration files of the project in a separate folder, so as not to clog the root. What files I want to move:

1. .prettierrc
2. .eslintrc
3. Shadcn files (tailwind.config.js, postcss.config.css, etc)
4. Possibly vite.config.ts (if this is even realistic)
5. tsconfig.json, tsconfig.node.json

Can you suggest how to do this in a painless way? I moved Prettier, it seemed ok, VSCode extension continued to work, but with ESlint the native extension stopped working already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When moving config files in a project, you need to make sure that you update file references for the moved files. This can usually be done inside of your package.json file. For example, for your ESLint file, there should be a section in your package.json that looks similar to this:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  // etc...
}
```

To update the file reference for this, change the following:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "./config/.eslintrc",
  // etc...
}
```

You'll want to update references for each config file that you move.

Comment: It worked. Great, thank you very much. Now the only thing left to figure out is how to transfer the rest of the files in my list...